# How do I allow user to add images with a Image Box

Tags: swiftui

I am relatively new this SwiftUI and I'm trying to build something to learn along the way. However I couldn't find much help on adding an Image "Button"? to allow user to insert a photo from their gallery or take a photo

Here is my code :)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case cost, item, description
    }

    @State private var cost: String = ""
    @State private var item: String = ""
    @State private var description: String = ""

    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Enter Amount ($)", text: $cost)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .cost)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                TextField("What did you spent it on?", text: $item)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .item)
                TextField("Description...",text: $description)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals:.description)
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Return") {
                        focusedField = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Any advice will be a great help for me as I just started out recently.

Comment: https://designcode.io/swiftui-advanced-handbook-imagepicker

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker